# Hot to make pandas cut have first range equal to minimum value

Tags: python, pandas, cut

I have this dataframe:

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
ser = pd.Series(lst)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(ser, columns=['Quantity'])
```

When i check unique values from variable quantity i have the following distribution:

```
df1.groupby(['Quantity'])['Quantity'].count() / sum ( df1['Quantity'])

Quantity
0    0.741935
1    0.338710
2    0.016129
3    0.209677
Name: Quantity, dtype: float64
```

Because value 2 represents only 0.016 i want to create a new categorical variable that creates "bins" like:

```
Quantity 
0
1-2
3+
```

How the bins are created is not relevant, the rule of thumb is :
If a number has low representation, it should be aggregated with the other values in a class (bin) .

Other example:

```
Quantity 
0    2662035
1       1200
2          2
```

Could be converted in :

```
Quantity
0
1+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the bins the way you want in [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), by default the right part of the bins is uncluded:

```
import numpy as np

(pd.cut(df['Quantity'], bins=[-1, 0, 2, np.inf], labels=['0', '1-2', '3+'])
   .value_counts()
)
```

Output:

```
0      57
1-2    29
3+      5
Name: Quantity, dtype: int64
```

##### combining counts based on a threshold

```
threshold = 0.05
c = df1['Quantity'].value_counts(sort=False).sort_index()

group = c.div(c.sum()).gt(threshold).cumsum()

(c.reset_index()
  .groupby(group)
  .agg({'index': lambda x: f'{x.iloc[0]}-{x.iloc[-1]}' if len(x)>1 else str(x.iloc[0]),
        'Quantity': 'sum',
        })
  .set_index('index')
 )
```

Output:

```
       Quantity
index          
0            46
1-2          22
3            13
```

Comment: But the labels vary depending on the variable and what makes sense in each one

Comment: @mafalda can you clarify the logic? Or maybe give another example?

Comment: Yes of course. I will edit my post

Comment: I updated please let me know if it is clear now

Comment: @mafalda unfortunately not, I understand that you want to dynamically compute the bins, but I have no idea of the logic that you want to use

Comment: i think now it is clear explained

Comment: It's better, but how should it generalize? If below a fixed threshold, add to the previous group? Then it might be more efficient not to use `cut` but to post-process the output of `value_counts`. Do you **need** to use `cut`?

Comment: I added some code for what I **think** you want ;)

Comment: thank you!! I do i use this to replace the values of the variable with the "index" values?